# WebView should not open links in browser

Tags: java, android

How do I make WebView to open link in WebView itself instead of browser?

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dsaif);
    runDialog(5);
    WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    engine.loadUrl("http://android.dsaif.tk/store/");
}
```

Please give full code with fixes as I'm very new to Android Development. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dsaif);
    runDialog(5);
    WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    engine.loadUrl("http://android.dsaif.tk/store/");
    engine.setWebViewClient( new HelloWebViewClient() );
} 



  private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url ) {                 

         return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code.........

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.share_email);
    webE = (WebView)viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.webE);
        webE.loadUrl("http://some url");
        webE.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
 }

 class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced this problem in our project too. And we solved it by using jQuery Mobile in web side of project. Then i can suggest you to use jQuery Mobile if you are coding the webside of your project .