# How to make a native android application behave like web app inside one only activity?

Tags: android

I have a native android app in which there are two activities, 1st activity contains a button and on action of button I want to start the 2nd activity. Content of seconds activity will be from a website. **Is it possible to make the 2nd activity behave like webapp ?**

If I use WebView in this case, it is displaying the website inside the activity but when I try to interact with the website, it ask to open it in the browser which I don't want. I want to interact with the website within the activity.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code... for open link in WebView itself instead of browser...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);       
    WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    engine.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/store?hl=en");
    engine.setWebViewClient( new HelloWebViewClient() );
} 



 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url ) {                 

     return false;
  }
}
```

see this link for more details... [WebView should not open links in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477214/webview-should-not-open-links-in-browser)

Comment: Thanks Man..!!
You save my day.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set the baseURL property when creating the Webview, you'll get what you  want.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying.
But I use WebView in this case, it is displaying the website inside the activity but when I try to interact with the website, it ask to open it in the browser which I don't want. I want to interact with the website within the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create you're own Webview where you can override the default behaviour:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would I know the url which the user is requesting after baseurl ?
For example - At first, I can load the base url in the webview, then user clicks a button in the website. Now how would I know the url of the page which button refers to ?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I can't test it at the moment, but I would think that in the method above (shouldOverrideUrlLoading) the parameter "url" is the url the link / button links to.
Did you try it out?