# set loader on webview

Tags: android, webview

i want to set progress dialog on webview activity,below is my code , i dont know exactly where i should use loader.

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apnikheti);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");

}

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: Start a `ProgressBar` before calling the web url and dismiss it on `onPageFinished()` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a Progress Dialog in a webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849347/adding-a-progress-dialog-in-a-webview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Horizontal progress bar:**

In your xml file, do the following changes

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/urlContainer" />
```

In your WebViewActivity, do the following changes

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());

progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progress.setMax(100);

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient { 
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {          
        WebViewActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);        
}
```

**For progress dialog:**

In your layout xml file, do the following changes

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/urlContainer" />
```

In your WebViewActivity, do the following changes

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {   
     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

     @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);             
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

     @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
}
```

Check here for more details [ProgressBar while Loading WebView in Android](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/progressbar-while-loading-webview)

**Update:**

Checkout here to [open link in WebView itself instead of browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742334/how-to-make-a-native-android-application-behave-like-web-app-inside-one-only-act/12742632#12742632)

Comment: i want all the child links of my website open in in same activity instead of default browser

Comment: for that you need to return false in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method every time.

Comment: Check my updated answer to open child links of website in same activity instead of default browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use webviewclient in this way.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
        if (progrDialog == null) {
            progrDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
            progrDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progrDialog.show();
        }
    }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        try{
        if (progrDialog.isShowing()) {
            progrDialog.dismiss();
            progrDialog = null;
        }
        }catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```